# Upload File to a server using Protocol Buffer in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

My objective is to chunk a file and then use a streaming connection to send the file to a server using gRPC++. Can somebody confirm whether the below code works for the client?

My proto file has a single object "bytes"

```
message FileContent {
  bytes content = 1;
}
```

Client Code

```
char *buffer = new char[2048];
// Open a stream-based connection with the gRPC server
std::unique_ptr<ClientWriter<FileContent> > writer(this->service_stub->Store(&context, &fileack));

// send the file name to the server
filecontent.set_content(filename);
std::cout << "Client: RPC call with File Name:" << filecontent.content() << endl;
writer->Write(filecontent);

// Get a file handle for the file we want to upload and the file length 

fileStream.open(filename, ios::binary);


while (!fileStream.eof())
{
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
     filecontent.clear_content();
     fileStream.read(buffer,2048);
     filecontent.set_content(std::string(buffer, 2048));
     writer->Write(filecontent);
}
```

Server Code

```
    Status Store(ServerContext* context, ServerReader<FileContent>* reader, FileAck* fileack) override {

 FileContent filecontent;
 ofstream fileStream;
 std::string serverfilepath;

 if (fileStream.is_open())
 {
     std::cout << "Reading Data";
     while (reader->Read(&filecontent))
     {
         std::cout << "Reading Data";
         fileStream << filecontent.mutable_content();
     }

     fileStream.close();
 }

 else
 {
    reader->Read(&filecontent);
    fileStream.open(serverfilepath, ios::binary);
 }

 return Status::OK;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protobuf `bytes` type generates a field of type `std::string` on the C++ side. Your `char *buffer` is thus implicitly converted to an `std::string`.

The problem is that the [constructor](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) used for this expects a null-terminated string, but your `buffer` does not have a terminator byte (nor can it, because it may contain `\0` bytes in the middle). This may cause the `std::string` constructor to run over the end of the buffer looking for the terminator byte.

To fix this, construct the `std::string` with a length explicitly:

```
filecontent.set_content(std::string(buffer, 2048));
```